# How do I create a WebPartPage using PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, powershell

I need to learn a PS script to create a WebPart Page on any library I want in my Sharepoint 2010 site.
Im brand new to PowerShell and Sharepoint, so far all I know is the little tought on a few MVAs I've done, so please go easy on the explanations lol

Thanks in advance, I hope to return the favor someday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a webpart page, then understand below parameters which we will use in the function.

1. $webUrl - Mandatory - SharePoint Web Url - e.g. http://server:port/
2. $WebPartPageName - Mandatory - New page name
3. $WebPartPageLibraryName - Mandatory - Parent Library name for new page
4. $pageLayout - Mandatory - Page Layout code - Int

Refer the full function below (Referred from: [SharePoint 2010: Create a Blank WebPart Page using PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19610.sharepoint-2010-create-a-blank-webpart-page-using-powershell.aspx) )

```
function CreateBlankWebpartPage            
{            
    [CmdletBinding()]            
    Param(            
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]            
        [string]$webUrl,            
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
        [string]$WebPartPageName,            
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
        [string]$WebPartPageLibraryName,            
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
        [int]$pageLayout    
    )                 

    Start-SPAssignment -Global              
    $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl                
    $pagesLibrary = $spWeb.Lists | Where { $_.Title -eq $WebPartPageLibraryName }               
    if ($pagesLibrary -eq $null) {             
        Write-Host -f red "WebPart Page Library - $WebPartPageLibraryName Not exists."              
        return               
    }            

    Write-Host -f yellow "Creating New Webpart page $WebPartPageName in library $WebPartPageLibraryName"            
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("/" + $pagesLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/" + $WebPartPageName + ".aspx")            
    $flagConfirm = 'y'            
    if($spFile.Exists -eq $true)            
    {            
        $flagConfirm = Read-Host "Page $WebPartPageName already exists in library $WebPartPageLibraryName, do you want to recreate(y/n)?"             
    }            

    if ($flagConfirm -eq 'y' -or $flagConfirm -eq 'Y')            
    {            
        Write-Host -NoNewLine -f yellow "Creating New Webpart page $WebPartPageName "            

        $cmd ='' + $pagesLibrary.ID + 'NewWebPageNewWebPartPage' + $pageLayout + 'true'+ $WebPartPageName +'';
        $spWeb.ProcessBatchData($cmd)
        write-host -f Green "...Success!"
        #Add weppart in Webpart page
        foreach($listItem in $pagesLibrary.Items)
        {
            if($($listitem.URL).Contains("$WebPartPageName" + ".aspx"))
            {
                $myListItem = $listItem
                break;
            }
        }
        $pageUrl =  $($myListItem.URL)
        Write-Host -f yellow "New page Url - $pageUrl"
    }
    Stop-SPAssignment -Global
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$webUrl = "http://sever:port"            
$WebPartPageLibraryName = "DocLib1"            
$WebPartPageName =  "MyWPPage"            
$pageLayout = 1             
CreateBlankWebpartPage $webUrl  $WebPartPageName $WebPartPageLibraryName $pageLayout
```

These are page layouts available for New page.

1. Full Page, Vertical
2. Header, Footer, 3 Columns
3. Header, Left Column, Body
4. Header, Right Column, Body
5. Header, Footer, 2 Columns, 4 Rows
6. Header, Footer, 4 Columns, Top Row
7. Left Column, Header, Footer, Top Row, 3 Columns
8. Right Column, Header, Footer, Top Row, 3 Columns

Comment: There is XML missing, just as in the source article, at this line: $cmd ='' + $pagesLibrary.ID + 'NewWebPageNewWebPartPage' + $pageLayout + 'true'+ $WebPartPageName +'';

Answer (score 2):

Click the below msdn link ,This example script can be used to create blank webpart page in a Non-Publishing SharePoint web

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19610.sharepoint-2010-create-a-blank-webpart-page-using-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is [this beautiful blogpost](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19610.sharepoint-2010-create-a-blank-webpart-page-using-powershell.aspx) which explains the PS script to create WebPart Page in any library.